# Could an old Raspberry Pi 1 (Model B, rev 1, 256MB Ram) view YouTube video smoothly?

Tags: video

I am using an old Raspberry Pi 1 (Model B, 256MB Ram) with Raspbian 2012-8-16 version. I bought it in August 2012 and leave it unused for some time. Recently, I set it up again and try to view YouTube videos using the web browser (Midori 0.4.3). However, I find that the browser seems having a problem in streaming YouTube videos, I could only see a black box in the video area inside the browser.

From this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmlt0iUPLY8&app=desktop), it shows that a Raspberry Pi Model B (512mb) could view video smoothly.

It seems that the free memory left in my Pi is only 10K. The output from the `free` command is:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        188112     177128      10984          0       3668      29908
-/+ buffers/cache:     143552      44560
Swap:       102396         92     102304
```

Is lack of memory a key problem for my Raspberry Pi to view videos?

Does anyone have experience in using a Raspberry Pi Model B (256MB Ram) to view YouTube videos? Is this task possible? If yes, what OS (and version) and what application(s) should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a first generation model B (256MB ram) that I watch YouTube videos on  all the time. From my experience there are a couple of things that will effect playback:

1. Your network connection, if you have a slow or flaky connection you will encounter issues.
2. choice of OS, I had issues trying to use various browsers on Raspbian.
3. Power supply, I had issues with the system freezing after several hours; these were eventually tracked down to a weak power supply.

Assuming that number one is not an issue (I don't know a way around this other than downloading the videos first -  a quick google search will turn up several ways to do this). besides replacing the power supply, I installed raspbmc (now super-seeded by [OSMC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/osmc-stable-release/)), this is a dedicated media center distribution, and  the YouTube plugin. This has the advantage that it is optimized for playing video. I have also added an IR remote control and the raspbmc app to my tablet to control the media center.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Sorry for a late lookup of your answer.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the YouTube plugin that you have described. Is it a plugin for a web browser or for the raspbmc OS.

Comment: I think my problem may be due to my midori web browser which may not have a flash plugin. Yesterday I have tried the "omxplayer" program in a most recent version of Raspbian. I find that a downloaded mp4 video could be viewed smoothly in my 256MB ram Raspberry Pi. That means that the 256MB ram Raspberry Pi has the capability of showing video smoothly.

Comment: Nevertheless, my internet connection may be not fast enough and/or the 256MB ram Raspberry Pi seems handle desktop windows not fast enough.

Comment: The youtube plugin is for raspbmc (osmc)

Comment: Ok, I'll then try osmc.

Comment: After several days of trying the OSMC (2015-08-01 version with youtube addon) in my Raspberry Pi Model B (256MB ram), it gives satisfactory viewing experience to me. It's great. Thanks.